# How to append a file to Fom data, send it to server and then get the file BACK?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

I want to post some data together with a file as form data to the server and then fetch the data and the file back.

**Create and Post Form Data**

```
  let formDataStory = new FormData(); // create form formData
  formDataStory.append('file',story.file); // add file to formData
  formDataStory.append('title', story.title); // add title to formData
  formDataStory.append('content', story.content); // add content to formData;
  this.props.createStory(formDataStory) // Create Story
```

**Get Form Data Back**

```
this.props.getStory(id)          // passing Story ID
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          story: response.data  // Getting FormData 
        });
```

Now `story.file` is no longer understood as a file, but only as a string. How do I actually get the file back from the server if I previously sent it as Form Data?

Comment: are you trying to append the data from your form to the file you're uploading? also, will this be an express server?

Comment: Yes i append the data to the file. I dont use an express server. My set up is react frontend and django (rest api) backend. @Farnoosh